# Как исправить ошибку ant?

Tags: android, android-studio, cmd, ant

Что я делаю не так ?

```
D:\android-project>ant debug install

Buildfile: D:\android-project\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
D:\android-project\build.xml:91: Cannot find D:\Android\Sdk\tools\ant\build.xml imported from D:\android-project\build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Вы ведь пытаетесь собрать SDL2, правильно? Тогда почему `ant`? Помню, что SDL2 его когда-то использовал, но сейчас в ридми написано собирать с помощью gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools

Удалены эти скрипты ещё год назад в Revision 25.3.0 (March 2017).

Obsolete/deprecated tools have been removed:

- android
- ddms (instead see Using DDMS)
- draw9patch (instead see Draw 9-patch)
- hierarchyviewer (instead see Profile Your Layout with Hierarchy Viewer)
- traceview (instead see Profiling with Traceview and dmtracedump)
- **ant scripts**
- Project and activity templates

Если хотите использовать, ставьте старую версию SDK.